# Next JS 14 cookie management for Login with Django

Tags: django, next.js, cookies, next.js13

So, I am using nextjs 14 with Django as my backend and so far, things have been quite difficult to get working but I like the combination. Now, I have to authenticate users and so far, I have a client form that has a function handler which calls a server action. I tried passing the server action directly, but I am not sure how to pass errors and show them in the form.

I am using redux and rtk query for client-side requests as per the redux recommendations. My previous workflow before using nextjs was to send a request to the Django Api and if the credentials are valid the response would include necessary data like the access token and a http only cookie containing the refresh token. The access token would be put in the state and if it expires the `refreshtoken` api would be called to refresh both tokens.

This approach works and you can tell me if its secure (all over https ofc). But, for experimentation now I have the form use a server-side action and inside it calls the login Api but now the refresh token is included in the response. When the action receives the response if it's successful it strips out the `refreshtoken` property and puts it in a cookie that again is http only. The result is the same but now it is not such a pain to manage the cookie in the front-end with cross-site and all. This approach also means that to refresh the tokens it must go through a server side action as the cookie does not seem to send to Django if I access it directly with rtk query.

Is this latter unnecessary? I am mostly coming from a servers load approach as now the request has to go to nextjs which then calls the Django Api. What are the benefits of using a server side action? Since I am using postgres it means a call to nextjs then a call to django and then a call the the database.

```
try {
        const data = { "email": formData.get('email') as string, "password": formData.get('password') as string }
        let response:LoginMerchant = await loginAPICall(data)
        let refreshToken = response.refresh_token
        if(refreshToken){
            cookies().set('refresh', refreshToken, {sameSite:'none', secure:true, httpOnly:true})
            delete response.refresh_token
        }
        return response as LoginMerchant
    }
```